# Convert MAX( KEEP( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY, CASE) statement into Spark SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, apache-spark-sql, translation

I am having a hard time with converting this Oracle code into Spark SQL.

```
SELECT STUDY_ID, POSITION_ID, STATUS
FROM
(SELECT t2.STUDY_ID, t2.POSITION_ID
, (SELECT MAX(
    t1.CODE || '~' || DATE || '~' || COMMENT)
    KEEP (
    DENSE_RANK LAST
    ORDER BY
    t1.DATE
    ,
    CASE 
    WHEN t1.CODE IN ('READY TO BEGIN') THEN 1
    WHEN t1.CODE IN ('IN PROGRESS') THEN 2
    WHEN t1.CODE IN ('FINISHED') THEN 3
    ELSE 10
    END
    )
FROM TABLE1 t1
WHERE t2.POSITION_ID = t1.POSITION_ID
AND t1.CODE IS NOT NULL
) STATUS
FROM TABLE2 t2,
TABLE3 t3
WHERE t2.STUDY_ID = t3.STUDY_ID
)
WHERE STATUS IS NOT NULL
```

So far I have tried replacing the part before CASE WHEN with PARTITION BY, ORDERED BY t1.DATE DESC since DENSE_RANK specifies LAST. I also tried different window functions that produce different results than the base query. I am fairly new to the SQL world and I find this conversion to be really confusing. I tried asking AI for help however it does not quite understand what this query is trying to achieve.
The results should be:
Multiple POSITION_IDs for multiple STUDY_IDs each having their latest STATUS, e.g.:

| STUDY_ID | POSITION_ID | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1111 | READY TO BEGIN~01.01.2000~BEGIN |
| 123 | 1112 | FINISHED~02.01.2000~FINAL |

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the Oracle query as:

```sql
SELECT t2.study_id,
       t2.position_id,
       t1.status
FROM   TABLE2 t2
       INNER JOIN TABLE3 t3
       ON t2.STUDY_ID = t3.STUDY_ID
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT position_id,
                code || '~' || date || '~' || comment AS status,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                  PARTITION BY position_id
                  ORDER BY
                    date DESC,
                    CASE code
                    WHEN 'READY TO BEGIN' THEN 1
                    WHEN 'IN PROGRESS'    THEN 2
                    WHEN 'FINISHED'       THEN 3
                                          ELSE 10
                    END DESC,
                    comment DESC
                ) AS rn
         FROM   TABLE1
         WHERE  code IS NOT NULL
       ) t1
       ON (t1.position_id = t2.position_id AND t1.rn = 1);
```

I do not use Apache Spark but Spark SQL appears to support [`CASE` expressions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#case) and the [`ROW_NUMBER` analytic function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#row_number) so you may be able to use that query (or you may also need to translate `code || '~' || date || '~' || comment` to `CONCAT(code, '~', date, '~', comment)`).

*Note: `status` will never be `NULL` in this version of the query as it contains `'~'` literals, which will never be `NULL`.*

Comment: Thank you! I have a slight count mismatch now and the rows are not ordered the way they should be but it definitely is a step in the right direction :)

Comment: @gjuliano In SQL (of most dialects, not just Oracle) result sets are non-deterministically ordered (i.e. unordered) unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause. Your first query does not use an `ORDER BY` clause so it is unclear why you would expect the second query to have the same order. If you want a specific order then you will need to add an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: As for the count mismatch, if [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77249655/edit) and provide the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for some sample data that replicates the issue then I can try to debug it; but without sample data it is going to be difficult.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned this but the query I provided is included inside a source qualifier in Informatica. Not sure why it is ordered when I run it in Oracle because as you said, order by clause is not specified here. Unfortunately I will not be able to provide sample data, however we sometimes get small count mismatches because data I am working with has migrated over. Appreciate your feedback!